# How to disable outside interaction until the form is closed or a button is clicked?

Tags: vb.net

How do I disable any interaction or activity in my system until my active form is closed or a button is clicked?

I want to make a form with the nature of a message box in which this form has a countdown timer. In any case that the user closes the form or click an abort button, the user receives a penalty that increases the time on the timer on its next instance. Thus, I can't allow the user to just minimize or tray my form or change tabs.

Comment: Creating ransomware is not a built-in feature for vb.net.  There is absolutely nothing you can do cause the user of the machine to lose control over the system, the OS won't allow it.  Minimizing a window or clicking another taskbar button does not cause a timer to stop ticking, so there's no point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Show your form as dialog like:

```
Dim frmNew As Form1 = new Form1()
frmNew.showDialog()
```

after that use event to catch form before it is closing, and add your penalty first to your database, and close the form.